# React not re-rendering upon state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop, state, rendering

I’m building a chess app using OOP atm and it’s built in a Next.JS framework. I've done some refactoring in the app and it now isn't re-rendering the objects on the screen when the state changes. It will suddenly render the right stuff if I make the server re-compile by moving a console.log around, but any time I want anything to re-render on the screen/ update I am having to do that now. The main thing I changed is the board component below, am I doing something wrong in it? any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

```
import createSquares from '../functions/createSquares';
import calculateCheck from '../functions/calculateCheck';
import calculatePossibleMoves from '../functions/calculatePossibleMoves';
export default class ChessBoard {
  constructor() {
    this.arrayOfSquares = createSquares();
    this.squareSelected = undefined;
    this.playerTurn = 'White';
    this.playerInCheck = false;
    this.potentialMoves = calculatePossibleMoves(this);
  }
  selectSquare(square) {
    this.squareSelected = square;
    this.potentialMoves = square.chessPieceContained.legalMoves;
  }
  movePiece() {
    this.playerTurn = this.playerTurn === 'White' ? 'Black' : 'White';
    this.squareSelected = undefined;
    this.potentialMoves = calculatePossibleMoves(this);
    this.playerInCheck = calculateCheck(this);
  }
}
```

** edit **

The rendering is taking place in this component:

```
export default function Board({ board }) {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
        position: 'relative',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        height: '41vh',
        width: '41vh',
        border: '0.5vh solid black',
      }}>
      {board.arrayOfSquares.map((square) => {
        let p = square.chessPieceContained;
        let color = square.black ? 'brown' : 'cream';

        return (
          <div
            key={`${square.gridValue[0]}${square.gridValue[1]} `}
            onClick={() => {
              square.readyPiece(board);
            }}
            style={{
              height: '5vh',
              width: '5vh',
              position: 'relative',
              border: '0.1vh solid black',
              backgroundColor: color,
            }}>
            {p ? (
              <div className={p.selected ? 'highlight' : null}>
                <p.image />
              </div>
            ) : null}
          </div>
        );
      })}
      {board.potentialMoves
        ? board.potentialMoves.map((coordinate) => {
            let top = coordinate[1] * 5 + 0.1;
            let left = coordinate[0] * 5 + 0.1;
            return (
              <div
                key={`${top} ${left}`}
                onClick={() => {
                  let square = board.arrayOfSquares
                    .filter(
                      (tile) =>
                        tile.gridValue[0] === coordinate[0] &&
                        tile.gridValue[1] === coordinate[1]
                    )
                    .pop();
                  if (
                    square.gridValue !== board.squareSelected.gridValue &&
                    board.squareSelected !== undefined
                  ) {
                    square.movePiece(board);
                  }

                  board.arrayOfSquares.forEach((square) => {
                    if (square.highlighted) {
                      square.setHighlight();
                    }
                  });
                }}
                style={{
                  position: 'absolute',
                  top: `${top}vh`,
                  left: `${left}vh`,
                  height: '4.8vh',
                  width: '4.8vh',
                  opacity: '0.5',
                  borderRadius: '50%',
                  backgroundColor: 'yellow',
                }}></div>
            );
          })
        : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Where in this code are you updating state in React?  You may be calling functions on setting values on your objects, but unless you're using React to update the state then nothing will trigger React to re-render.

Comment: Sorry, David, it's being rendered in the Board component I have just added and Its isn't re-rendering anymore when I change any of the states other than when I make a new instance of the board when it will reset.
I have a square class contained in the array of squares that contains instances of a chess piece class  and it wont show the pieces moving around the board anymore.

Comment: *"when I change any of the states"* - But where in the code shown are you changing state in a way that React observes?  For example, in class-based React components you would normally use `this.setState()` to update the state.  In functional components with React hooks you'd use the "set" function returned by `useState()` to update state.  If you're using Redux you'd dispatch an action to update state.  Updating your variables (often called "mutating state directly") doesn't trigger React to do anything.  You may need to refer back to some React tutorials to learn about state.

Comment: Oh, okay, so I have my board in a stat on my index page, does this mean any time I modify the state I will need to actively update the state React sees using setState?

Comment: If you want React to respond to that update, yes.

Comment: Okay, thanks David